# Default values not populating for a cascading parameter in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, default, reportbuilder

I have two parameters that cascade from a date parameter. The first cascading parameter is able to populate and defaults to selecting all labels (this is what I want). The second successfully populates the values but defaults to selecting none (this is what I want to fix). I have verified that both are returning their respective default values from a query - and I know the query is good for the problematic parameter because it populates with available selections successfully, it just wont default to selecting them all.

Are there any issues with having two parameters cascade from a single one? Any issues in the result set that would successfully return labels for a parameter but would not be valid for default values?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Answer was posted in the comments by OP:

> I was returning a NULL value which was keeping me from being able
>   select all in a multi-attribute parameter. I am now handling this with
>   a CASE statement checking for NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I have reports that have multiple parameters cascading from a single one, so I don't think that's the problem.

My hunch is that something isn't right in the parameter. To troubleshoot this, set the value field and the Label field for the Available Values and the default values all to be the exact same field from the same dataset. (Use the one that was originally the Value field for the parameter.) If you "select all" do you get all the data you expect?

Comment: I was returning a NULL value which was keeping me from being able select all in a multi-attribute parameter. I am now handling this with a CASE statement checking for NULL.